# Error message enabling fstrim.service

Tags: filesystem, fstab, services, trim

I have been running Ubuntu 20.04 desktop since last February.

Today I issued `sudo systemctl enable fstrim.service` and I got this message:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

Then I checked to see if the service is already enabled, so I issued `journalctl -fu fstrim` and got “Logs begin at Sun 2022-07-10 07:55:26 PDT” followed by a listing of events on August 8 and August 15.

Finally, I issued `systemctl status fstrim.service` and got the following message:

```
fstrim.service - Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service; static; vendor preset:>
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: fstrim.timer
       Docs: man:fstrim(8)
```

So it looks like fstrim is already running, and was enabled by default when I installed Ubuntu back in February.  My questions are:

(1) What is the significance of those messages shown above from ``sudo systemctl enable fstrim.service?

(2) It appears that it runs once a week, on Mondays.  Is that frequent enough, or too frequent?  How can I change the trim frequency if I need to?

(3) As it was enabled out of the box, are there any other options that are recommended to enable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. fstrim will automatically be installed when the installer sees an SSD.

- What is the significance of those messages shown above from `sudo systemctl enable fstrim.service`?

Besides the reasons already shown this is also shown when the service is already running. It gets triggered when there is already a symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

- It appears that it runs once a week, on Mondays. Is that frequent enough, or too frequent? How can I change the trim frequency if I need to?

Yes. No. And from the manual:

> Running fstrim frequently, or even using `mount -o discard`, might  nega‐
> tively affect the lifetime of poor-quality SSD devices.  For most desk‐
> top and server systems the sufficient  trimming  frequency  is  once  a
> week.

and see the `fstrim.timer` service. It has a "weekly" in there:

```
$ more /usr/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks once a week
Documentation=man:fstrim
ConditionVirtualization=!container
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/initrd-release

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
AccuracySec=1h
Persistent=true
RandomizedDelaySec=6000

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

- As it was enabled out of the box, are there any other options that are recommended to enable?

No. It is recommended to not change any of them.

But besides what `fstrim.timer` provides as features the manual on `fstrim` has 4 options that manipulate what `fstrim` does:

> By default, fstrim will discard all unused blocks in the filesystem.
> Options may be used to modify this behavior based on range or size, as
> explained below.

The options it refers to are:

> -o, --offset offset
> Byte offset in the filesystem from which to begin searching for
> free blocks to discard. The default value is zero, starting at the
> beginning of the filesystem.
>
> ```
>    -l, --length length
>        The number of bytes (after the starting point) to search for free
>        blocks to discard. If the specified value extends past the end of
>        the filesystem, fstrim will stop at the filesystem size boundary.
>        The default value extends to the end of the filesystem.
>
>    -I, --listed-in list
>        Specifies a colon-separated list of files in fstab or kernel
>        mountinfo format. All missing or empty files are silently ignored.
>        The evaluation of the list stops after first non-empty file. For
>        example:
>
>        --listed-in /etc/fstab:/proc/self/mountinfo.
>
>  -m, --minimum minimum-size
>        Minimum contiguous free range to discard, in bytes. (This value is
>        internally rounded up to a multiple of the filesystem block size.)
>        Free ranges smaller than this will be ignored and fstrim will
>        adjust the minimum if it’s smaller than the device’s minimum, and
>        report that (fstrim_range.minlen) back to userspace. By increasing
>        this value, the fstrim operation will complete more quickly for
>        filesystems with badly fragmented freespace, although not all
>        blocks will be discarded. The default value is zero, discarding
>        every free block.
> ```